# Exporting php for-loop table to csv: working but prints page html and duplicated entries in csv file

Tags: php, csv

Am trying to create a custom export to CSV for woocommerce orders. The code works so far, but the csv file printed looks weired. The entire page html is printed in the csv file, with the desired loop/table only appearing at the bottom. Looking at the table, it also appears that entries are doubled - like order ID 1558 appear twice in succession, and this repeats for all entries. I a have spent hours over here looking for solutions especially doing away with html in the csv file. Most solutions suggest that I put the header functions at the top, other suggest that I remove html from the code. I have tried all these but it seems am still missing something. I am using elementor, and created an html button in the frontend. Am now trying to use this button to call the csv file download. Please help.

```
function orderscsvdownload(){
if (isset( $_POST['export'] ) ) {// when button on the page is clicked
    $fromdate = $_POST['fromDate'];
    $todate = $_POST['toDate'];

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'shop_order' ),
        'posts_per_page' => 30,
        //'paged' => $paged,
        
    'limit' => -1, 
);

    $tablecontents= wc_get_orders($args);

    $fileName = "phpzag_export_".date('Ymd') . ".csv";

      $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

      $header = array("Id", "Name", "Item", "Value", "Date");
      fputcsv($file, $header); 
foreach ($tablecontents as $content) {
     $orderData = array();
       $orderData[] = $content->get_id();
       $orderData[] = $content->get_total();
       $orderData[] = $content->get_status();
       $orderData[] = $content->get_billing_first_name();
       $orderData[] = $content->get_date_created();
      // ob_end_clean(); 
    fputcsv($file, $orderData);

          fputcsv($file, $orderData);
      }
      fclose($file);
      header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
    header("Content-Type: application/csv;");   

exit;


}



}


add_shortcode('csvdownload','orderscsvdownload');// i had to add this shortcode on the page for the download to work. Sort of calls this function on the page for the download to work.
```

Comment: Problem is that you are trying to do this from within a shortcode callback function. Those get executed _while_ WordPress is parsing your post content, it is well in the process of writing HTML output at that point already. This could perhaps be solved by discarding the output buffer content (if output buffering was already "on" at that point, you'd have to check) - but a more clean solution would be to define a dedicated "route" for this using the WP Rest API, and then handle the download part in there. https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. But am actually a novice and going this way may be complicated....but let me do some more research.

Comment: @GeorgeObonyo *"Looking at the table, it also appears that entries are doubled":*
yes you are writing the CSV rows twice , look at the lines after `// ob_end_clean();`: there are two `fputcsv(`

Comment: Hi there @Pippo, I noticed this and corrected many ours ago. Appretiate your support. And after 1 and half a day, i finally got a working code. I will share as an answer to this post.

Answer (score 0):

Life is good again after more than 20 hours! I got the code working.This is not a pro solution, but makes me proud, and  works for novices like me who are struggling with doing ajax calls, jQuery and can't even figure out how to retrieve something from wpdb. You are welcome to improve the answer.

```
function orderscsvdownload() {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array( 'shop_order' ),
            'posts_per_page' => 1000,
            //'paged' => $paged,
            'post_status' => array( 'wc-processing','wc-eviction-notice'),
        'limit' => -1, 
    );  
    //ob_get_clean();
    
    if (isset( $_POST['export'] ) ) {// when button on the page is clicked
        $fromdate = $_POST['fromDate'];
        $todate = $_POST['toDate'];
        ob_get_clean(); 
        $tablecontents= wc_get_orders($args);
        ob_get_clean();
        $fileName = "Homa_".date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";
        ob_get_clean();
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");   
        ob_get_clean();
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");  
        ob_get_clean();
        header("Content-Type: application/csv;"); 
        ob_get_clean();
        $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    
        $header= array("Idy","Name","Item","Value","Date");
    
        //ob_end_clean();   // works with here
        
        fputcsv($file, $header); 
        
        foreach ($tablecontents as $content) {
            //ob_end_clean();
            $orderData = array();
            $orderData[] = $content->get_id();
            $orderData[] = $content->get_total();
            $orderData[] = $content->get_status();
            $orderData[] = $content->get_billing_first_name();
            $orderData[] = $content->get_date_created();
    
            // ob_get_clean();
            fputcsv($file, $orderData);
    
            // fputcsv($file, $orderData );
        }
    
        fclose($file);
        exit;
    }
    
    $html='<div>
    
    <form method="post">
    
        From: <input type="date" name="fromDate"/>
        To: <input type="date" name="toDate"/>
    
        <input type="submit" name="export" value="Export to CSV" class="btn btn-default" />

    </form>
    </div>';

    // ob_get_clean($html);
    return $html;   
}

add_shortcode('csvdownload','orderscsvdownload');//
```

I had to add this shortcode on the page for the download to work. Sort of calls this function on the page for the download to work